# Overwrote my presentation with a new blank file, now can't recover it

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, file-recovery, microsoft-office-2013

I had a PowerPoint file with 140 slides that accidentally overwrote with a new blank file of the same name.

1. I always save my files on SharePoint but this time I forgot it.
2. I tested applications like Active Recovery and others in quick scan, but they can only restore deleted files, not the last version.
3. I [searched the Internet](http://www.freerecoverytools.com/file/restore-retrieve-deleted-ms-powerpoint-2003-2007-2010-2011-2013-Windows-mac/) and found a solution, but it didn't help.

   > Several days ago I inadvertently deleted a Powerpoint Presentation I
   >   was working on. I checked my reclycle bin and it wasn’t there. How can
   >   I get it back? 
   >        If your important Powerpoint presentation has been accidentally deleted from your computer’s hard driver, you don’t have to start over
   >   from scratch with a new file. You can restore the deleted Powerpoint
   >   file with a file-recovery tools. The program will scan your computer’s
   >   hard driver thoroughly and retrieve the lost PPT files even if you
   >   have emptied the PPT files from Windows recycle bin or Mac trash bin.
4. I checked the folder for recovered unsaved presentations here:

   ```
   C:\Users\staba\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\UnsavedFiles
   ```

   But there aren't any deleted files.
5. I checked the NTFS properties of my drive and files, but versioning is not activated.

Comment: there isn't anything you can do. You overwrote an unsaved file with a blank one & saved it. I'm afraid it's lost

Comment: @Sathya solved. because in Quick scan run that. i rerun that and recover my file.

Comment: Saber, we know English is not your first language, however most of your posts have had to be edited in some way. Please at least take care of proper capitalization (i.e., always "I" instead of "i", and sentences start with a capital letter), so your posts are easier to read. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running applications like [Active Recovery](http://www.file-recovery.net/) in full scan mode (super scan, like this picture) instead of Quick Scan mode (as I have done previously) solved my problem.

When you save a new file over an existing one, the files are not actually overwritten and deleted – they're created again with the same name.

Every time you save a file, the Operating System creates a new file on the disk and the last versions are still there -- But you must be careful, don't write anything to your disk or defrag it!

With a full scan you can recover them.

[image]

Comment: "The files are not overwritten and deleted (...)  the last versions are still there" -- partially true. When you delete a file, what happens is the disk sectors where the files resid are ***marked as available for new files***. If you write a new file and it gets saved onto these sectors, recovery is very unlikely. That's the reason for not writing anything to a disk where there's a file you need to recover.

Answer (score 1):

For a MAC I used EraseUS a recovery product that recovered versions of the PPT file I had overwritten. Phew. Many hours work recovered.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Vista and higher versions there's a feature called *Previous Versions*. It's enabled if [Shadow Copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy) is turned on.

You can access it through **Previous Versions** tab in Properties of a file.

[image: Previous Versions tab in Properties]