# What is the autosave powerpoint file extension

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, file-extension

Following a windows PC crash, when asked if I wanted to save an autosave powerpoint presentation, I accidentally clicked no.

All my work was lost and the autorecover folder
`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\PowerPoint`
was empty.

The fact that it was there after the PC crash means it must be saved somewhere. But where and what file extension?

I'm using file recovery software and can recover deleted files etc. but cannot find the deleted file anywhere, it certainly is not obvious e.g. *.ppt. The closest I came was a version from the same day but it only has 165 bytes and starts with ~$.

Does anyone know where Powerpoint saves the autosave file when a PC crashes?

Comment: "The fact that it was there after the PC crash means it must be saved somewhere". Could it be that it was there (in some auto-recover folder), but once you accidentally pressed no it got deleted? Have you [checkedany similar questions](https://superuser.com/q/556581/141595)?

Comment: My assumption is that it got deleted.  However, it is not showing as a deleted files.  Only the reference to a deleted file is deleted, they can still be recovered.  I have checked everywhere to find an answer.  No joy.

Comment: Ok, that's a pity. And how about the similar question? Did you try the answer there? Was there simply no output in your case? Was there an error?

Comment: They may be the .pcb or .tmp files. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qk8mN.jpg)

Comment: @Emily can you add as an answer and I will accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autorecover files would be the .pcb or .tmp files as following image.

[image]

These files can not be opened directly, you need to use PowerPoint, click Open, locate to autorecover folder and set "All Files (*)" to find them to open.

Comment: Thanks, I found the .tmp files but if I'd know about the .pcb I might not have had to completely redo my project.  Hopefully this helps someone else stuck like me!

Comment: .TMP files might help. .PCB files probably will not. They're sort of relics of the old toolbar customization files PPT used to store pre-2007. I suspect they're still there because you can still customize toolbars in e.g. the VBA editor and a few other places.